# Chrome not connecting to network

Tags: django, google-chrome, networking

I was wondering how I could let Chrome connect to my network. I am using a website called Codeanywhere.com and I was using a Django container. I used the built-in terminal and installed Python 3.4 and Django 10. I created a project and ran the server, and it said it had created one at this ip: http://127.0.0.1:8000/. However, whenever I try to access it, it the site can't be reached. If it helps, I am using a Chromebook Thinkpad, and it is a school computer. They do block things with Lightspeed Systems and they have a lot of blacklisting things going on. I am trying to learn Django for a project. Below is a screenshot of the screen when I try to access the server.

[My screenshot of the error screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDO7b.png)

I can't embed my image yet, I don't have 10 reputation points :/ It's a link instead.

Comment: Refer to this section `Why doesn't my stack work on 127.0.0.1:port?` on http://docs.codeanywhere.com/other/faq.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistake #1**

The server isn't located on your local host, so you need to go to the provided server. for example, when I opened a project I got this instruction:

```
To access your application over HTTPS, make sure your application is running on port 3000 and use the following link:

https://mysite-{username}551936.codeanyapp.com
```

**Mistake #2**

you should run the server with a specified ip commend - and use 0.0.0.0:3000 instead of the usual localhost, like so:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000
```

In addition, I would reccomend you to read the "mysite Container" file which explains everything about the setup in detail.